# How to remake html + vuejs code so that it works on a page with several posts?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

There is fully working code on the post editing page

```html
<a href="#" v-on:click="confirm = 1" v-show="!confirm" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
<span v-if="confirm">
    Are you sure?
    <a href="{{ route('admin:news:delete', $news->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="confirm = 0" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">No</a>
</span>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      confirm: 0
  }
});
```

I need the same functionality only on the page where the information for each post is displayed in the table. That is, if you see 10 lines, then you need a button for each line.

I tried to do this:

```html
<a href="#" v-on:click="confirm[{{ $news->id }}] = 1" v-show="!confirm[{{ $news->id }}]" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
<span v-if="confirm[{{ $news->id }}]">
    Are you sure?
    <a href="{{ route('admin:news:delete', $news->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="confirm[{{ $news->id }}] = 0" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">No</a>
</span>
```

And this:

```html
<a href="#" v-on:click="confirm[{!! $news->id !!}] = 1" v-show="!confirm[{!! $news->id !!}]" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
<span v-if="confirm[{!! $news->id !!}]">
    Are you sure?
    <a href="{{ route('admin:news:delete', $news->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="confirm[{!! $news->id !!}] = 0" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">No</a>
</span>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      confirm: []
  },
  created: function () {
        var items = this.confirm;
        var news = {!! $news->toJson() !!}
        news.data.forEach(function(element) {
            items[element.id] = 0;
        });
    }
});
```

But it does not work.

I think this is a common task and it has already been done many times, but I am new in vuejs and I don't know how to implement it.

Help me, please!

Comment: Are you displaying news with a PHP loop that generates the HTML, or via vuejs v-for ?

Comment: @tete0148: I displaying news with a PHP loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!!!

I don't know how it works, but it works!!! Please explain me.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: {},
        activeClass: 'active'
    },
    created: function () {
        var items = this.items;
        var news = {!! $news->toJson() !!};
        news.data.forEach(function(element) {
            items[element.id] = 0;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        setItemId1: function (item_id) {
            this.activeClass = 'active2';
            this.activeClass = 'active3';
            var items = this.items;
            Object.keys(this.items).forEach(function(key) {
                if (item_id == key) {
                    items[key] = 1;
                } else {
                    items[key] = 0;
                }
            });
        },
        setItemId0: function (item_id) {
            this.activeClass = 'active2';
            this.activeClass = 'active3';
            this.items[item_id] = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<button v-on:click="setItemId1({{ $news->id }})" v-bind:class="activeClass" v-show="!items[{{ $news->id }}]" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Delete</button>
<span v-if="items[{{ $news->id }}]">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.news.delete', $news->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="setItemId0({{ $news->id }})" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">No</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you store the $news variable in your component state, you have to access the news variable using the vuejs syntax: you don't need the $ before the variable names.

I think you are using v-for the display the news, but you try to insert PHP variable that doesn't exist.